# Simulating a system of batching jobs with interrupting set-up/switch-on times using Simpy

Tags: interrupt, simpy, batching

I am new to Simpy and have a problem with combining batching jobs and interrupting set-up time. So could you please help me?

I would like to create a system with servers that need time to set up before being ready to serve.
The system starts to set up whenever enough M (2, 3,...) customers are in the queue. If the number of customers in the system reaches the maximum number of K(50), the coming customer will balk.

When a batch( group of M customers) leaves the system, we check if there are M customers(a batch) who are waiting to be served. If so, we keep the server remaining ON, otherwise, we turn off the server immediately.

I found some code for quite the same problem in a Simpy google group about Covid test simulation that uses Stores Resources  and the answer for interrupting set-up time with Container Resources by Michael R. Gibbs
https://groups.google.com/g/python-simpy/c/iFYaDlL4fq0

[Interrupt an earlier timeout event in Simpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757880/interrupt-an-earlier-timeout-event-in-simpy)

I tried to combine 2 codes but It didn't work.

Example, when M = 2, K = 50

1. Customer 1 arrives and waits
2. Customer 2 arrives, enough 2 customers then request a server.
3. Server 1 is SETUP in t1 secs.
4. Customer 3 arrives and waits
5. Customer 4 enough 2 customers then request a server.
6. Server 2 is SETUP in t1 secs.
7. Server 1 is ON.
8. Customers 1 and 2 occupied server 1
9. Customer 1 and 2 completes the service and leaves the system.
10. Customers 3 and 4 occupied server 1 (because when server 1 finishes
11. Server 2 is still in the setup process)
12. Server 2 (still in SETUP mode) is turned off...
13. ... Customer 100 arrives and sees the system has 50 customers, then customer 100 balk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broke customer arrivals into two parts.  A first queue that where the customer waits until there is enough customers to make a batch.  When I have enough customers to make a batch, I do so, popping the batched customers from the batching queue, and putting the batch in a processing queue.  I count the customers in both queues to see if a arriving customer aborts entry.

When a batch is put in the processing queue, I also start up a server.  This means that the number of batches in the processing queue will equal the number of servers starting up.  This also means that when a server finishes starting up, there will be a batch to process.  Since there will never be a wait for a batch, I use a simple list for my queue.

When a batch starts up, it grabs a batch, and removes itself from the list of starting servers.  After the server finishes processing a batch, it checks if there is a batch in the processing queue.  If so, grab the batch and keep processing, but also kill the server that is starting up to process the batch.  If no batches in the processing queue, shut down.

Here is the code.  You should see in the log the queues max out and customers abort, but also see servers start to shut down towards the end

```
"""
Simulation of servers processing batches

Customers enter a queue where they wait for
enough customers to make a batch

If the there are too many customers in the queues
the arriving customer will abort

When a batch is made, it is put into a second 
processing queue where the batch waits to be processed.

When a batch is put into the processing queue, it
starts a server.  The server has a start up delay 
then loops by seizing a batch, process the batch, release
the batch, checking if another batch is in the 
processing queue.  If there is another batch, stop a server
that is starting up and process the batch, else end loop
and shutdown server

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs

"""

import simpy
import random

max_q_size = 50
batch_size = 2
server_start_time = 55
processing_time = lambda : random.triangular(5,20,10)
arrival_gap = lambda : random.triangular(1,1,1)

# there is no wating so normal lists are good enough
batching_q = list()
processing_q = list()
server_q = list() # servers that are still starting up

class Server():
    """
    Server that process batches

    Has two states: starting up, and batch processing
    """
    def __init__(self, id, env, processing_q, server_q):

        self.id = id
        self.env = env
        self.processing_q = processing_q
        self.server_q = server_q

        self.start_process = self.env.process(self.start_up())

    def start_up(self):
        """
        starts up the server, then start processing batches

        start up can be interrupted, stoping the server
        """

        # start up
        try:
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} starting up')
            yield self.env.timeout(server_start_time)

            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} started')

            self.env.process(self.process())
        
        except simpy.Interrupt:
            print(f'{env.now} server {self.id} has been interupted')

    def process(self):
        """
        process batches
        keeps going as long as there are batches in queue

        If starts second batch, also interupts starting up server
        """

        while True:
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} starting batch process')
            b = processing_q.pop(0)
            yield self.env.timeout(processing_time())

            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} finish batch process')

            if len(self.processing_q) > 0:
                # more processes to do,
                # steal batch from starting up server

                s = self.server_q.pop() # lifo
                s.stop()

            else:
                print(f'{env.now} server {self.id} no more batches, shutting down')
                break

    def stop(self):
        """
        Interrupts server start up, stoping server
        """
        try:
            self.start_process.interrupt()
        except:
            pass

def gen_arrivals(env, batching_q, processing_q, server_q):
    """
    Generate arring customers

    If queues are too big customer will abort

    If have enough customers, create a batch and start a server
    """

    id = 1
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(arrival_gap())

        q_size = len(batching_q) + (batch_size * len(processing_q))
        if q_size >= max_q_size:
            print(f'{env.now} customer arrived and aborted, q len: {q_size}')
        
        else:
            print(f'{env.now} customer has arrived, q len: {q_size}')

            customer = object()
            batching_q.append(customer)

            # check if a batch can be creatd
            while len(batching_q) >= batch_size:
                batch = list()
                while len(batch) < batch_size:
                    batch.append(batching_q.pop(0))

                # put batch in processing q
                processing_q.append(batch)

                # start server
                server = Server(id, env, processing_q, server_q)
                id += 1
                server_q.append(server)


# boot up sim
env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(gen_arrivals(env, batching_q, processing_q, server_q))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Sorry, I didn't mention that number of servers is limited. For example, the number of servers = 5, maybe I have to check if there are any servers available before starting up or something? I tried to set the number of servers = 5 and got an error.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: you need to track the number of servers.  I recommend doing that in the Server class with a class/static variable.  You can then use this variable to see if you are at your max before creating a new server.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your comment and it work. Also, I have one more question, when I turn off a server that is starting up, instead of #lifo rule, I want to turn off the first start-up server, so I execute the command "s = self.server_q.pop(0)". Then, I got an error like "pop from empty list". So, how can I fix it?

Comment: I would think you want to keep the server that will start the soonest, why churn startup time.  since we are not always starting a new server (because of the server limit) when a new batch is added, you need to add a if before the pop to see if there is anything to shut down.

Comment: yep, turning off the last server can save time to start up. But in some cases, it requires customers/jobs to change servers constantly. This makes it more difficult to monitor system output parameters.

Comment: add if statement before pop to see if the list is not empty

Comment: I post my code as another answer. I have a problem, can you take a look? Thanks!!!