# Simulation of servers processing batches with interrupting set-up/switch-on times

Tags: simulation, simpy, batching

I would like to create a system with servers that need time to set up before being ready to serve. The system starts to set up whenever enough M (2, 3,...) customers are in the queue. If the number of customers in the system reaches the maximum number of K(50), the coming customer will balk.

When a batch( group of M customers) leaves the system, we check if there are M customers(a batch) who are waiting to be served. If so, we keep the server remaining ON, otherwise, we turn off the server immediately.

This process has been done thanks to the answer by Michael R. Gibbs: [Simulating a system of batching jobs with interrupting set-up/switch-on times using Simpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75481639/simulating-a-system-of-batching-jobs-with-interrupting-set-up-switch-on-times-us)

I would like to add another policy to the system that the number of servers is limited. When I add a condition to limit the number of servers, it works until a server was interrupted or shut down. Then, these servers seem to have disappeared and are no longer active.

Here is my code:

```
import simpy
import random
import numpy as np

class param:
    def __init__(self, x):
        #self.FILE = 'Setup_time.csv'
        self.MEAN_INTERARRIVAL = x     # arrival_gap
        self.MEAN_SERVICE_TIME = 2      # processing_time
        self.MEAN_SWITCH_TIME = 3       # server_start_time
        self.NUM_OF_SERVER = 4          # maximum number of servers
        self.MAX_SYS_SIZE = 10           # maximum number of customers in the system
        self.BATCH_SIZE = 2
        self.RANDOM_SEED = 0

`# there is no wating so normal lists are good enough`

class Server():
    """
    Server that process batches

    Has two states: starting up, and batch processing
    """
    
    def __init__(self, id, env, processing_q, server_q, param):

        self.id = id
        self.env = env
        self.processing_q = processing_q
        self.server_q = server_q

        self.start_process = self.env.process(self.start_up(param))

    def start_up(self, param):
        """
        starts up the server, then start processing batches

        start up can be interrupted, stoping the server
        """
        global num_servers
         # start up

        if self.id <= param.NUM_OF_SERVER:         # I add the condition to limit the number of servers
            try:
                num_servers += 1
                print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} starting up')
                yield self.env.timeout(param.MEAN_SWITCH_TIME)
                #yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1/param.MEAN_SWITCH_TIME))

                print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} started')

                self.env.process(self.process(param))
            
            except simpy.Interrupt:
                print(f'{env.now} server {self.id} has been interupted-------------------')

    def process(self, param):
        """
        process batches
        keeps going as long as there are batches in queue

        If starts second batch, also interupts starting up server
        """
        global num_servers, num_active_server
        while True:
            num_active_server += 1

            b = processing_q.pop(0)
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} starting batch process')

            yield self.env.timeout(param.MEAN_SERVICE_TIME)
            #yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1/param.MEAN_SERVICE_TIME))

            num_servers -= 1
            num_active_server -= 1
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} finish batch process')

            if len(self.processing_q) > 0:
                # more processes to do,
                # steal batch from starting up server

                #if self.server_q:
                    #s = self.server_q.pop(0)        # Do these lines work for FIFO rule?
                    #s.stop()
                s = self.server_q.pop() # lifo
                s.stop()

            else:
                print(f'{env.now} server {self.id} no more batches, shutting down')
                break

    def stop(self):
        """
        Interrupts server start up, stoping server
        """
        try:
            self.start_process.interrupt()
        except:
            pass

def gen_arrivals(env, batching_q, processing_q, server_q, param):
    """
    Generate arring customers

    If queues are too big customer will abort

    If have enough customers, create a batch and start a server
    """
    global num_servers, num_balk, num_cumulative_customer, num_active_server
    id = 1
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(param.MEAN_INTERARRIVAL)
        #yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1/param.MEAN_INTERARRIVAL))
        num_cumulative_customer += 1

        customer = object()                         
        batching_q.append(customer)

        q_size  = len(batching_q) + (param.BATCH_SIZE * len(processing_q)) 
        sys_size = q_size + (num_active_server * param.BATCH_SIZE) 

        #if q_size > max_q_size:
        if  sys_size > param.MAX_SYS_SIZE:    # I check the limited condition for number customer in system instead of number customer in queue
            num_balk += 1

            batching_q.pop(-1)                # I added the statement  
            print(f'{env.now} customer arrived and aborted, sys len: {sys_size }')

        else:
            #customer = object()                         # I moved these 2 lines above to update system size before using the if statement
            #batching_q.append(customer)

            print(f'{env.now} customer has arrived, q len: {q_size}, sys len: {sys_size}')
            # check if a batch can be creatd
            while len(batching_q) >= param.BATCH_SIZE:
                batch = list()
                while len(batch) < param.BATCH_SIZE:
                    batch.append(batching_q.pop(0))

                # put batch in processing q
                processing_q.append(batch)

                # start server
                server = Server(id, env, processing_q, server_q, param)
                id += 1
                server_q.append(server)

        #Calculate balking probability
        prob_balk = num_balk/num_cumulative_customer
        #print(f'{env.now} prob_balk {prob_balk}')
        list_prob_balk.append(prob_balk)


`# boot up sim`
trial = 0
Pb= []    #balking probability
global customer_balk_number
for x in range(1,3):
    trial += 1
    print('trial:', trial)

    batching_q = list()
    processing_q = list()
    server_q = list() # servers that are still starting up
    num_servers = 0                     # number of server in system (both starting and serving server)
    num_active_server = 0               # number of servers serving customers
    num_balk = 0                        # number of balking customers
    num_cumulative_customer = 0         # total arriving customers
    
    list_prob_balk = []    #list balk prob each trial   

    paramtest1 = param(x)
    random.seed(paramtest1.RANDOM_SEED)

    # create and start the model
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(gen_arrivals(env, batching_q, processing_q, server_q, paramtest1))
    env.run(30)

    Pb.append(list_prob_balk[-1])

#print('List of balk prob', Pb )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saw two issues with your code.

First, when checking if the queue of starting up servers is not empty you need to use `if len(self.server_q) > 0:` not `if self.server_q:`

Also, your tracking of server count and active count were a bit off.  Your active count was counting the number of batches being processed. not active servers.

I also had a error in my original code were I forgot to remove the server from the server startup q when the server became active.

Here is the fixed code

```
import simpy
import random
import numpy as np

class param:
    def __init__(self, x):
        #self.FILE = 'Setup_time.csv'
        self.MEAN_INTERARRIVAL = x     # arrival_gap
        self.MEAN_SERVICE_TIME = 2      # processing_time
        self.MEAN_SWITCH_TIME = 3       # server_start_time
        self.NUM_OF_SERVER = 4          # maximum number of servers
        self.MAX_SYS_SIZE = 10           # maximum number of customers in the system
        self.BATCH_SIZE = 2
        self.RANDOM_SEED = 0

# there is no wating so normal lists are good enough`

class Server():
    """
    Server that process batches

    Has two states: starting up, and batch processing
    """
    
    def __init__(self, id, env, processing_q, server_q, param):

        self.id = id
        self.env = env
        self.processing_q = processing_q
        self.server_q = server_q

        self.start_process = self.env.process(self.start_up(param))

        global num_servers
        # sever has started, but not active 
        num_servers +=1
        

    def start_up(self, param):
        """
        starts up the server, then start processing batches

        start up can be interrupted, stoping the server
        """
        global num_servers
         # start up

        # self.id is not a count its a unique id for each server
        #if self.id <= param.NUM_OF_SERVER:         # I add the condition to limit the number of servers

        try:
            #num_servers += 1
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} starting up')
            yield self.env.timeout(param.MEAN_SWITCH_TIME)
            #yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1/param.MEAN_SWITCH_TIME))

            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} started')

            # server has started, need to remove from startup q
            self.server_q.remove(self)

            self.env.process(self.process(param))
        
        except simpy.Interrupt:
            print(f'{env.now} server {self.id} has been interupted-------------------')

            # server is stoping, need to adjust server count
            num_servers -= 1

    def process(self, param):
        """
        process batches
        keeps going as long as there are batches in queue

        If starts second batch, also interupts starting up server
        """
        global num_servers, num_active_server
        # count server becoming ative only once
        num_active_server += 1

        while True:
            # server becomes active only once, this is counting batches processed
            # num_active_server += 1

            b = processing_q.pop(0)
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} starting batch process')

            yield self.env.timeout(param.MEAN_SERVICE_TIME)
            #yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1/param.MEAN_SERVICE_TIME))

            # Server is still running
            # num_servers -= 1
            # num_active_server -= 1
            print(f'{self.env.now} server {self.id} finish batch process')

            if len(self.processing_q) > 0:
                # more processes to do,
                # steal batch from starting up server

                # #if self.server_q:
                #     #s = self.server_q.pop(0)        # Do these lines work for FIFO rule?
                #     #s.stop()
                # s = self.server_q.pop() # lifo
                # s.stop()

                # need to check the length, not if it exists
                if len(self.server_q) > 0:
                    s = self.server_q.pop(0)
                    s.stop()

            else:
                print(f'{env.now} server {self.id} no more batches, shutting down')
                break
        
        # now the server is shutting down
        num_active_server -= 1
        num_servers -= 1

    def stop(self):
        """
        Interrupts server start up, stoping server
        """
        try:
            self.start_process.interrupt()
        except:
            pass

def gen_arrivals(env, batching_q, processing_q, server_q, param):
    """
    Generate arring customers

    If queues are too big customer will abort

    If have enough customers, create a batch and start a server
    """
    global num_servers, num_balk, num_cumulative_customer, num_active_server
    id = 1
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(param.MEAN_INTERARRIVAL)
        #yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1/param.MEAN_INTERARRIVAL))
        num_cumulative_customer += 1

        customer = object()                         
        batching_q.append(customer)

        q_size  = len(batching_q) + (param.BATCH_SIZE * len(processing_q)) 
        sys_size = q_size + (num_active_server * param.BATCH_SIZE) 

        #if q_size > max_q_size:
        if  sys_size > param.MAX_SYS_SIZE:    # I check the limited condition for number customer in system instead of number customer in queue
            num_balk += 1

            batching_q.pop(-1)                # I added the statement  
            print(f'{env.now} customer arrived and aborted, sys len: {sys_size }')

        else:
            #customer = object()                         # I moved these 2 lines above to update system size before using the if statement
            #batching_q.append(customer)

            print(f'{env.now} customer has arrived, q len: {q_size}, sys len: {sys_size}')
            # check if a batch can be creatd
            while len(batching_q) >= param.BATCH_SIZE:
                batch = list()
                while len(batch) < param.BATCH_SIZE:
                    batch.append(batching_q.pop(0))

                # put batch in processing q
                processing_q.append(batch)

                # start server
                if num_servers < param.NUM_OF_SERVER:
                    server = Server(id, env, processing_q, server_q, param)
                    id += 1
                    server_q.append(server)

        #Calculate balking probability
        prob_balk = num_balk/num_cumulative_customer
        #print(f'{env.now} prob_balk {prob_balk}')
        list_prob_balk.append(prob_balk)


# boot up sim`
trial = 0
Pb= []    #balking probability
global customer_balk_number
for x in range(1,3):
    trial += 1
    print('trial:', trial)

    batching_q = list()
    processing_q = list()
    server_q = list() # servers that are still starting up
    num_servers = 0                     # number of server in system (both starting and serving server)
    num_active_server = 0               # number of servers serving customers
    num_balk = 0                        # number of balking customers
    num_cumulative_customer = 0         # total arriving customers
    
    list_prob_balk = []    #list balk prob each trial   

    paramtest1 = param(x)
    random.seed(paramtest1.RANDOM_SEED)

    # create and start the model
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(gen_arrivals(env, batching_q, processing_q, server_q, paramtest1))
    env.run(30)

    Pb.append(list_prob_balk[-1])

#print('List of balk prob', Pb )
```

Comment: I just run your code, and the number of servers is still unlimited (> NUM_OF_SERVER). You didn't use NUM_OF_SERVER in your code ?

Comment: I suppose the number of batches being processed and the active servers are the same. Because the active servers are servers working after the set-up process( servers in the set-up phase are not active).

Comment: updated code to limit the number of servers created.  This is done in the gen_arrivals func

Comment: Sorry, but I think the updated code to limit the number of servers doesn't work. The number of servers is still larger than NUM_OF_SERVER.

Comment: Whenever the number of servers in the system is less than NUM_OF_SERVER, it will create a new server, so the number of created servers will be infinite.

Comment: what params are you running with?  How can you tell?  Remember, the server id is not the count of servers in the system. Every time a server starts a new id is made, and when a server shuts down, its id is retired.  You can check by printing out the num_servers var to the log.

Comment: I got your point. But, is it possible without removing the id after the server shutdown? for example, there are only 4 servers with defined id, it works like a container, put/get when needed?

Comment: in this Paradyme, start and create are the same thing.  Currently, creating a server also starts the server.  A alternative would be to make a pool of NUM_OF_SERVER stopped servers, take out the call to start_up out of the __init__.  When a batch is created you would check if there is a server in the stopped pool.  If there is, pull it from the stopped pool, call the startup, and put it in the start_up pool.  When the server shuts down it will need to remember to put itself back into the stopped pool

Comment: Good luck.  Should not be a lot mods to the current code, but if you get stuck you can always drop another question.

Comment: Hello Michael, I have another question as I want to keep servers remain idle for a while before shutting down . I posted as a new question a few days ago but no one responded. Could you take a look. Thank you!